# Converting a switch statement to a lookup object

Tags: javascript

I was given a switch statement to convert into a lookup object, and I've tried everything and it's still not working. I would like if some of you take a look at these code snippets and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The switch statement:

```
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  var result = "";
  switch(val) {
    case "alpha":
      result: "Adams";
      break;
    case "bravo":
      result: "Boston";
      break;
  };
  return result;
};
```

My attempt at the lookup object:

```
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  var result = "";
  var lookup = {
    "alpha": "Adams",
    "bravo": "Boston",
  };
  return result;
};
```

Comment: How are you using the `lookup` variable?

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: and your attempt at the return? come on, you're one statement away from glory

Comment: Remove comma(,) right after Boston.

Comment: The given switch statement has syntax errors, your solution is totally fine :)

Comment: @aldi - yes, that's going to complete the code

Comment: @aldi thats not a syntax error, thats good style ;)

Comment: @JonasW. - no, there's no syntax error as such

Comment: Just try `lookup[val]`.

Comment: @jaromadaX but i don't think that duplicate labels are what this should do

Comment: oh, I didn't say the code was correct :p but it's not a syntax error

Comment: I think it was put on hold so fast, not even enough time to user explain or read the comments...

Comment: See this, it can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/9a40pvd2/3/

Comment: @Ricardo It is on hold until it becomes a clear and answerable question. That's what "on hold" means. It's not *deleted* nor *closed*.

Comment: Yes I know @deceze it wasn't a criticise, just commenting :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this implementations as a code example:

- one uses the `switch` function
- two uses the `lookup` object

As you can see the `one` function with the use of `switch` is not the best solution because has [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) 7, and also it is harder to read and maintain..

Instead, the function `two` with the use of `lookup` object is much more cleaner

Code example:

```js
function one(val) {
  let result = '';

  switch (val) {
    case 'alpha':
      result = 'Adams';
      break;
    case 'bravo':
      result = 'Boston';
      break;
  };

  return result;
}


function two(val) {
  const lookup = {
    'alpha': 'Adams',
    'bravo': 'Boston',
  };

  return lookup[val] || '';
}


console.log('one:', one('alpha'));
console.log('two:', two('alpha'));
```

Note that your switch statement has syntax errors.. Have been corrected in the code example

Comment: Thank you! It's working now

Comment: It is good to help